# how can I use aws credentials file for laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to use laravel's SQS queue w/out putting access key and secret in the config?  ie: use aws credentials file?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel instantiates a `SqsClient` [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8865d2276be94f0a3497ba3bd26c906ae9e91e1c/src/Illuminate/Queue/Connectors/SqsConnector.php#L16), passing through options from `app/config/queue.php`.

It looks like you're interested the `'profile'` option described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-sqs.html#factory-method).

```
use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;

$client = SqsClient::factory(array(
    'profile' => '<profile in your aws credentials file>',
    'region'  => '<region name>'
));
```

Seems to me you should just be able to set a `'profile'` option on your [queue config](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/queue.php#L52-L58)

```
'sqs' => [
    'driver'  => 'sqs',
    'profile' => '/path/to/your/credeitials/profile/here',
    'queue'   => 'your-queue-url',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
],
```